# Cypress how to check if an element contains a certain string

Tags: java, if-statement, cypress

Cypress how to check if an element contains a certain string?

I use a custom check if element exists code to check if the element can be found (An error message)
then I want to check if this element contains certain text?
or could I use the java function of query selector?

```
         cy.validateIfElementExistsInDomAsBoolean('[data-testid=alert-content]').then(bool => { // checks error to file see how it works
              if (bool) {
                if(cy.contains('[data-testid=alert-content]', "Your basket has been updated. Please refresh the basket to continue.")){
                  console.log("refresh site")
                 }else{
                    console.log("different error")
                      }
             }else{
                cy.log("Checked for error no error found")
              }
            })
```

Comment: It's not quite clear the purpose of your custom command. It would help if you shared that code and possibly an example on how to use it for you app.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you can make your custom command return the text or empty string

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('validateIfElementExistsInDomAsString', (selector) => {
  const $element = Cypress.$(selector);
  if ($element.length > 0) {
    return $element.text()
  } else {
    return ""
  }
})

cy.validateIfElementExistsInDomAsString('[data-testid=alert-content]')
  .then(error => {

    if (error === "") {
      cy.log("Checked for error no error found")
      return
    }

    if (error === "Your basket has been updated. Please refresh the basket to continue.") {
      console.log("refresh site")
    } else {
      console.log("different error")
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `validateIfElementExistsInDomAsBoolean` correctly returns a boolean value true or false, you can do something like this:

```js
cy.validateIfElementExistsInDomAsBoolean('[data-testid=alert-content]').then(
  (bool) => {
    // checks error to file see how it works
    if (bool) {
      cy.get('[data-testid=alert-content]')
        .invoke('text')
        .then((text) => {
          if (
            text ==
            'Your basket has been updated. Please refresh the basket to continue.'
          ) {
            cy.log('refresh site')
          } else {
            cy.log('different error')
          }
        })
    } else {
      cy.log('Checked for error no error found')
    }
  }
)
```

In case You have to do a partial string check, you can replace

```js
if (text=='Your basket has been updated. Please refresh the basket to continue.')
```

with

```js
if (text.toLowerCase().includes(
      'Your basket has been updated. Please refresh the basket to continue.')
)
```